# Meaning of the English word - Malta

Tags: meaning

what is the meaning of the word Malta .. I saw the word today on Google Maps[image]

Comment: I'll be interested to see what comes up here, to my knowledge Malta is an island in the Mediterranean and nothing else.

Comment: A lot of search results these days simply take whatever search term you're looking for and parrot it back, e.g., "10 best uses for **malta** in your kitchen!"  It's actually very frustrating.  This may be the result of someone else's search.

Comment: There isn't enough context to know for sure, but it's entirely possible that "malta" is referring to the [non-alcoholic barley/hops beverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malta_(soft_drink)) that is popular in the Caribbean and Latin America, and in Latino areas of North America. It has other names in other parts of the world, but usually with some form of the word 'malt'.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin 's answer seems to be the most plausible of all, considering the fact that the **m** in **malta** wasn't hyphenated.

Comment: @ParthaPratim Can you add all the context that people are requesting? Otherwise this will be closed as unclear. Maybe even give a link to google maps so people can explore the context there?

Answer (score -1):

Per a comment by Jeff Zeitlin:

> There isn't enough context to know for sure, but it's entirely possible that "malta" is referring to the [non-alcoholic barley/hops beverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malta_(soft_drink)) that is popular in the Caribbean and Latin America, and in Latino areas of North America. It has other names in other parts of the world, but usually with some form of the word 'malt'

Comment: It seems weird to convert into an answer a comment that is definitely not an answer, but is only suggesting something with the hopes of getting more context. Sadly the OP has not provided context yet.

Comment: @Mitch It certainly looked like an answer to me—and one that was phrased as well as I could have done. Had it actually been an answer, I would have upvoted it. The first thing I thought when I read the question was, "Oh, it's talking about the drink."